# TextField.setHieght(100); Doesn't work in ie?

Tags: extjs, textfield

I use this code to set a textfield height, but it doesn't work in IE (8),

Any one know why?

Comment: Please provide detailed information about "IT doesn't work".

Comment: You should atleast provide some code, also you title has a huge typo in it. it's `setHeight(100);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe caused by a typo? I guess it should be:

```
TextField.setHeight(100);
```

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Comment: @Wesley done. I'll have a look how I can help.